# Emulate a table cell without needing a UITableView (re-using standard iOS UI)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm creating a settings/edit profile view in my iOS app, which has a mix of text inputs, and cells which simply push a new View Controller onto the Nav Controller stack, ie.

[image]

However, to me that looks like a standard UITableViewCell with an image view on the left and an accessory view on the right. Could I leverage this control for my View, without needing to create a whole UITableView? Obviously I could re-create this with UIImageViews and UILabels but I was wondering if there was a better, more efficient way of creating this UI?

Comment: Why not just use a tableview?  It isn't much work

Comment: @Paulw11 Very true, just feels like a lot for 2 cells!

Comment: The text inputs can be cells in a tableview too.

Comment: It is possible to use a cell as a stand-alone view, just like any other UIView subclass, but you won't get any selection behavior, so there's no reason to do so in your case.

Comment: A table view brings you a lot of benefits. If you can make the entire view a UITableViewController you get keyboard avoidance and scrolling for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have often implemented such screens easily directly in my storyboards with static cells. Agreed, you need a tableview, but you get all the advantages (e.g. scrolling if the keyboard covers up any cells) practically for free without any additional code. You just write what you would write if you would recreate the interface with labels and image views and such.